# counter and displaylist AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

**How can I connect my counter to my display list?**
I've got a *counter* and a *displaylist* working, but I need help with everything in between.

**Try to explain**
I finished a Snowflake tutorial. The snowballs are children that are called to the stage. When connected to a dynamic variable, they move around and look like snow. I want my counter to move numbers around. I've got a counter, and I've got a 'for loop' to add children to the stage.

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/so_.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/so_.jpg)

*link to file*
http://sandboxfun.weebly.com/

*actionscript-3*

```
                 //DISPLAYLIST "puts stuff on stage"
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        var t:MovieClip = new Tee();
        t.x = 105 + i * 111;
        addChild(t);100
        }


//ARRAY 
//var o:Object = new Object(); <br>
//var TeeProps:Dictionary= new Dictionary(true); <br>
//var Tees:Array = new Array(); <br>
//TeeProps[t] = o; <br>
//addChild(t); <br>
//Tees.push(t); <br>
//} <br>



                 //COUNTER drop in "mytext" text field to see it work
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);  
    var count:int = 0; //start at -1 if you want the first decimal to be 0  
    var fcount:int = 100; 

    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);  
    timer.start();  

    function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {  
      count++;  
      fcount=int(count*count/1000);//starts out slow... then speeds up 
     // mytext.text = formatCount(fcount);
    }

    function formatCount(i:int):String { 
         var fraction:int = i % 100; 
         var whole:int = i / 100;  

        return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" + fraction : fraction); 
    }
```

***I'm rebuilding a earlier version for learning purposes.***

Answer (score 0):

I attached the counter to the display list. It's like the example, but I changed the *for loop* to display numbers across. http://sandboxfun.weebly.com/

```
//-------------------------IMPORT METHODS--------------------------------------- 
        import flash.display.DisplayObject;  
        import flash.display.MovieClip;  
        import flash.utils.Dictionary;  
        import flash.events.Event;  
        //import caurina.transitions.Tweener;  

//-----------------------TIMER---------------------------------------        
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);// 
    //var timer:Timer;   
    var count:int = 0;  
    var fcount:int = 0;  
    var _listItems:Array = new Array(); 
    var previousNums:Array; 
    const numHeight:int = 120; 
    //var numbers:NumbersView; 
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);   
    timer.start();  

//-----------------------COUNTER-CONT----------------------- 
    function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {   
      count++;   
      fcount=int(count*count/1000);//starts out slow... then speeds up  
    //  mytext.text = formatCount(fcount); 
    NumbersView(1); 
    //} 

//----------------------ZERO PLACE HOLDERS----------------------- 
    } 
    function formatCount(i:int):String {  
         var fraction:int = i % 100;  
         var whole:int = i / 100;   
      return ("000000000" + i).substr(-9, 9);  
       // return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" + fraction : fraction);  
    }  

    // 

//----------------------DISPLAY for loop, integer to string "puts numbers on stage" 
    function NumbersView($n:int):void { 
     //function NumbersView()// 
     //{ 
        _listItems = new Array(); 
        previousNums = new Array(); 
        var item:NumberImage; 
        var offset:int = _listItems.length; 
        //for (var i:int = 0; i < $n; i++) 
     for (var i:Number = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        { 
           item = new NumberImage(); 
           //item.x = (i + offset) * 9; 
           //item.y = (i + offset) * 9; 
        item.x = i * item.width;  
           _listItems.push(item);  
           addChild(item); 
        } 

//----------------------SPLIT STRING "pass to Tweener or some other method"--------------- 
    // 
       function setTime($number:String):void {  
                var nums:Array = $number.split("");  
                for (var i:Number = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {  
                if (nums[i] == NumbersView[i]) continue;  
                //Tweener.removeTweens(NumbersView[i]);  
                }
       }
     }
```